# How do I use "mean" as the final reducing function in a transducer?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to estimate the mean distance of all pairs of points in a unit square.
This transducer returns a vector of the distances of x randomly selected pairs of points, but the final step would be to take the mean of all values in that vector. Is there a way to use `mean` as the final reducing function (or to include it in the composition)?

```
(defn square [x] (* x x))
(defn mean [x] (/ (reduce + x) (count x)))

(defn xform [iterations]
  (comp
   (partition-all 4) 
   (map #(Math/sqrt (+ (square (- (first %) (nth % 1)))
                       (square (- (nth % 2) (nth % 3))))))
   (take iterations)))

(transduce (xform 5) conj (repeatedly #(rand)))

[0.5544757422041136
 0.4170515673848907
 0.7457675423415904
 0.5560901974277822
 0.6053573945754688]


(transduce (xform 5) mean (repeatedly #(rand)))
Execution error (ArityException) at test.core/eval19667 (form-init9118116578029918666.clj:562).
Wrong number of args (0) passed to: test.core/mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement your `mean` function differently, you won't have to collect all the values before computing the mean. Here is how you can implement it, based on [this Java code](https://yokolet.com/2017/05/29/online-algorithm.html):

```
(defn mean
  ([] [0 1]) ;; <-- Construct an empty accumulator
  ([[mu n]] mu) ;; <-- Get the mean (final step)
  ([[mu n] x] ;; <-- Accumulate a value to the mean
   [(+ mu (/ (- x mu) n)) (inc n)]))
```

And you use it like this:

```
(transduce identity mean [1 2 3 4])
;; => 5/2
```

or like this:

```
(transduce (xform 5) mean (repeatedly #(rand)))
;; => 0.582883812837961
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of `transduce`:

> If init is not supplied, (f) will be called to produce it. f should be
> a reducing step function that accepts both 1 and 2 arguments, if it
> accepts only 2 you can add the arity-1 with 'completing'.

To disect this:

1. Your function needs 0-arity to produce an initial value -- so `conj`
   is fine (it produces an empty vector).
2. You need to provide a 2-arity function to do the actual redudcing
   -- again `conj` is fine here
3. You need to provide a 1-arity function to finalize - here you want
   your `mean`.

So as the docs suggest, you can use `completing` to just provide that:

```
(transduce (xform 5) (completing conj mean) (repeatedly #(rand)))
; → 0.4723186070904141
```

If you look at the source of `completing` you will see how it produces
all of this:

```
(defn completing
  "Takes a reducing function f of 2 args and returns a fn suitable for
  transduce by adding an arity-1 signature that calls cf (default -
  identity) on the result argument."
  {:added "1.7"}
  ([f] (completing f identity))
  ([f cf]
     (fn
       ([] (f))
       ([x] (cf x))
       ([x y] (f x y)))))
```